# Sort a sequence (a sub-array in a array) in decreasing order by their elements (elements in the sub-array of an array)

Tags: c#, icomparable

I have been trying for days to find a solution for this problem using c#. I was able to sort them by length but I cannot figure out the solution to sort the array by from their left-most to their right-most.

The hint they gave is to define a class Sequence to hold a sequence of elements. We will implement `IComparable<Sequence>` to compare sequences by length in decreasing order (and by elements in decreasing order when the length is the same). Later we will use our TreeMultiSet class. Inside we will keep the first 10 sub-sequences of S, i.e. multi-set of the lucky sub-sequences of P, kept in decreasing order by length (and in decreasing order of their content when the length is the same). When we have 10 sub-sequences inside the multi-set and we add 11th sequence, it would take its correct place in the order, because of the `IComparable<Sequence>` defined. After that we can delete the 11th subsequence, because it is not amongst the first 10

Here is the problem:

We are given a sequence P containing L integers L (1 < L < 50,000) and a number N. We call a “lucky sub-sequence within P” every subsequence of integers from P with a sum equal to N. Imagine we have a sequence S, holding all the lucky sub-sequences of P, kept in decreasing order by their length. When the length is the same, the sequences are ordered in decreasing order by their elements: from the leftmost to the rightmost. Write a program to return the first 10 elements of S

Example: We are given N = 5 and the sequence P = {1, 1, 2, 1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, -1, 2, 3}. The sequence S consists of the following 13 sub-sequences of P:

```
[1, -1, 2, 3, -1, 1] 
[1, 2, 1, -1, 2]
[3, -1, 1, 2]
[2, 3, -1, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, -1, 2, 3]
[1, -1, 2, 3]
[-1, 1, 2, 3]
[5, 1, -1]
[2, 3]
[2, 3] 
[2, 3]
[5]
```

My solution:

Actually, when reading the hint I was not able to understand the idea so I came up with another way.

```
class Find
    {
        //Function to manually create an array with N elements
        public static int[] ArrCreate(int n, int[] Arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return Arr;
        }
        //Create a Dictionary class type to hold sub-array with sum of sub-array equal to given number k
        public static Dictionary<int, ArrayList> SubSeqEqual2N()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input k: ");
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input n element to create an Array: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] Arr = new int[n];
            int[] newArr = ArrCreate(n, Arr);
            int keyIndex = 0;
            //ArrayList arlist = new ArrayList();
            Dictionary<int, ArrayList> SeqofLuckyArr = new Dictionary<int, ArrayList> { };
            //Create a loop to find sub-array with the sum equal to given number K.
            for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length; i++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < newArr.Length; j++)
                {
                    sum = sum + newArr[j];
                    if (sum == k)
                    { 
                        //When sub-array with the sum equal to given number K is found then add them into a temp Arraylist, also increment the keyIndex.
                        keyIndex++;
                        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
                        for (int ko = i; ko <= j; ko++)
                        {
                            temp.Add(newArr[ko]);
                        }
                        //DEBUG PURPOSE
                        /*Console.Write("{");
                        foreach (var hehe in temp)
                        {
                            
                            Console.Write("{0}", string.Join(", ", hehe));
                            
                        }
                        Console.Write("}");
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        arlist.AddRange(temp);*/
                        //Then add that temp array as value into a Dictionary <key,value>type with that KeyIndex.
                        SeqofLuckyArr.Add(keyIndex,temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            //DEBUG PURPOSE
            //My method to sort the sub-array in the Dictionary by sub-array length and by key index.
            foreach(KeyValuePair<int,ArrayList> kvp in SeqofLuckyArr.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count).ThenBy(y => y.Key))
            {
                Console.Write("Key={0} ",kvp.Key);
                Console.Write(",");
                Console.Write("Value={ ");
                foreach (var hoho in kvp.Value)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", string.Join(", ", hoho));
                }
                Console.WriteLine("}");
                Console.WriteLine("");
                arlist.AddRange(kvp.Value);
            }
            //DEBUG PURPOSE
            return SeqofLuckyArr;
        }
    }
```

I try to find the sub-array with the sum equal to the given number K first then add them into the Dictionary as value with its key as index. Then sort -sub-array by length use OrderByDecreasing method.

The result:

```
Key=4 ,Value={ 1 -1 2 3 -1 1 }

Key=2 ,Value={ 1 2 1 -1 2 }

Key=1 ,Value={ 1 1 2 1 }

Key=3 ,Value={ 1 -1 2 3 }

Key=6 ,Value={ 2 3 -1 1 }

Key=7 ,Value={ 3 -1 1 2 }

Key=8 ,Value={ -1 1 2 3 }

Key=12 ,Value={ 1 -1 2 3 }

Key=11 ,Value={ 5 1 -1 }

Key=5 ,Value={ 2 3 }

Key=9 ,Value={ 2 3 }

Key=13 ,Value={ 2 3 }

Key=10 ,Value={ 5 }
```

But the result is not the same as the example. My problem is that I am stuck at "***When the length is the same, the sequences are ordered in decreasing order by their elements: from the leftmost to the rightmost***". As I thought left-most to right most is the key index of the sub-array from low to high.

Can anyone help me to find the appropriate way to order the sub-array in decreasing order by the elements? If my edition is not also appropriate to ask on SO I will delete my question.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before asking us to do your homework it would be highly appreciated to see what you have done yourself so far with the hints you've already been given. From there we can help you pointing out what is missing.

Comment: Can you please let us know what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck?  Your question mentions using `TreeMultiSet` but you don't share that with us or even explain what it is.  It's fine to ask about homework, but as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, *... you must have made a good faith attempt to solve it yourself. The question must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.*  Thanks!

Comment: See also [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I will update my work so far in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem lies solely in your ordering. The contents of the sequences are identical to the example.

First, the line you are ordering doesn't quite follow the rules specified:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,ArrayList> kvp in SeqofLuckyArr
                                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count)
                                           .ThenBy(y => y.Key))
```

> [...] kept in decreasing order by their length. When the length is the same, the sequences are ordered in decreasing order by their elements: [...]

The first ordering seems correct (`OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Count)`) by descending order of the sequences' length. The second ordering is currently ordered by the sequences' "key index" **and** in ascending order. This should have been in descending/decreasing (`ThenByDescending`) order based on the contents of the "lucky sub-sequences".

One way you can fix all this is by introducing an `IComparer` implementation a bit similar to the hint given. The `IComparer` below is able to take two sequences (`int[]`) as input and tell which of the two should come before the other (see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1.compare?view=net-5.0) for an explanation of what the return value of `IComparer.Compare` means):

```
public class IntArrayComparer : IComparer<int[]>
{
    public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        // Ensure we don't get a null-ref exception further down
        if (x == null || y == null)
            // x should come before (-1) or after (1) y (default ascending order)
            return y == null ? -1 : 1;
        
        // If the lengths are different, the length is the first ordering priority
        if (x.Length != y.Length)
            // Use the built-in 'CompareTo' method for the 'int' type
            return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);
        
        // Lengths are the same, so we compare the contents
        for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            var comparison = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
            // If the elements in the two seq. are different, we return the ordering
            if (comparison != 0)
                return comparison;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Now the previous mentioned line with your ordering becomes a little simpler (subjective opinion :)):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<int,ArrayList> kvp in SeqofLuckyArr
                                           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value, new IntArrayComparer()))
```

Check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dTDd1v) for a test run of the ordering part.

**Hint**: You actually don't even need to store your subsequences in a `Dictionary` - a `List` would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your solutioin. It works like a charm. I follow your hint using List + IComparer and implement them into my code and the output sastify the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response. After referring the Imcomparer implementation above. I was able to get the output the same as example. Here is my code for anyone facing the same issues as me.

```
class Find
    {
        public static int[] ArrCreate(int n, int[] Arr)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                Arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            return Arr;
        }
        public static void SubSeqEqual2N()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input k: ");
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Input n element to create an Array: ");
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] Arr = new int[n];
            int[] newArr = ArrCreate(n, Arr);
            //int keyIndex = 0;
            //ArrayList arlist = new ArrayList();
            //Dictionary<int, ArrayList> SeqofLuckyArr = new Dictionary<int, ArrayList> { };
            
            //Create a List of int array to store 
            List<int[]> luckyArray = new List<int[]>{ };
            for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length; i++)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                for (int j = i; j < newArr.Length; j++)
                {
                    sum = sum + newArr[j];
                    if (sum == k)
                    {
                        //keyIndex++;
                        ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
                        for (int ko = i; ko <= j; ko++)
                        {
                            temp.Add(newArr[ko]);
                        }

                        //Convert ArrayList temp into int array for applying IComparer.Compare<Int[],Int[]>
                        int[] luckySubArray = temp.ToArray(typeof(int)) as int[];
                        luckyArray.Add(luckySubArray);

                        //SeqofLuckyArr.Add(keyIndex,temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            var orderedSeq = luckyArray.OrderByDescending(s => s, new IntArrayComparer());           
            foreach(var seq in orderedSeq)
            {
                Console.Write("[ ");
                foreach (var i in seq)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", string.Join(", ", i));
                }
                Console.Write(" ]");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }
    }
    public class IntArrayComparer : IComparer<int[]>
    {
        public int Compare(int[] x, int[] y)
        {
            // Ensure we don't get a null-ref exception further down
            if (x == null || y == null)
                // x should come before (-1) or after (1) y (default ascending order)
                return y == null ? -1 : 1;

            // If the lengths are different, the length is the first ordering priority
            if (x.Length != y.Length)
                // Use the built-in 'CompareTo' method for the 'int' type
                return x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length);

            // Lengths are the same, so we compare the contents
            for (var i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                var comparison = x[i].CompareTo(y[i]);
                // If the elements in the two seq. are different, we return the ordering
                if (comparison != 0)
                    return comparison;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And the output:

```
[ 1 -1 2 3 -1 1  ]
[ 1 2 1 -1 2  ]
[ 3 -1 1 2  ]
[ 2 3 -1 1  ]
[ 1 1 2 1  ]
[ 1 -1 2 3  ]
[ 1 -1 2 3  ]
[ -1 1 2 3  ]
[ 5 1 -1  ]
[ 2 3  ]
[ 2 3  ]
[ 2 3  ]
[ 5  ]
```